# NetworkX: Iterate through Graphs with for loop

Tags: python, networkx

assume I have four different graphs in a project and I want to iterate through them by using for-loops. First of all, the graph structure will look like this:

```
import networkx as nx
Gx = nx.DiGraph()
Gx.add_node('x1', server = 5)
Gx.add_node('x2', service = 3)
Ga = nx.DiGraph()
Ga.add_node('a1', server = 8)
Ga.add_node('a2', service = 4)
Gb = nx.DiGraph()
Gb.add_node('b1', server = 12)
Gb.add_node('b2', service = 5)
Gc = nx.DiGraph()
Gc.add_node('c1', server = 5)
Gc.add_node('c2', service = 3)
```

Now, I want to go through every graph and select one node randomly, after this set the attribute = 0 (e.g. simulating a server fail). So my function should look something like this:

```
for 'every graph' in 'DiGraphs':
     random_node = random.sample(Gx/a/b/c.nodes, 1)
     new_value_random_node = random_node['attribute'] * 0
```

Which would then throw out the graph structure like this after executing the code:

```
import networkx as nx
Gx = nx.DiGraph()
Gx.add_node('x1', server = 5)
Gx.add_node('x2', service = 0)  # service fail
Ga = nx.DiGraph()
Ga.add_node('a1', server = 0)  # server fail
Ga.add_node('a2', service = 4)
Gb = nx.DiGraph()
Gb.add_node('b1', server = 0)  # server fail
Gb.add_node('b2', service = 5)
Gc = nx.DiGraph()
Gc.add_node('c1', server = 5)
Gc.add_node('c2', service = 0)  # service fail
```

Summarizing I want to do two things:
**1. Go through every Graph (Gx,Ga,Gb,Gc)**
**2. In every graph -> select one node randomly**
**3. Set attribute of random node (either server or service) = 0**

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following:

```
import networkx as nx
Gx = nx.DiGraph()
Gx.add_node('x1', server = 5)
Gx.add_node('x2', service = 3)
Ga = nx.DiGraph()
Ga.add_node('a1', server = 8)
Ga.add_node('a2', service = 4)
Gb = nx.DiGraph()
Gb.add_node('b1', server = 12)
Gb.add_node('b2', service = 5)
Gc = nx.DiGraph()
Gc.add_node('c1', server = 5)
Gc.add_node('c2', service = 3)

import random
for graph in [Gx, Ga, Gb, Gc]:
     random_node = random.sample(graph.nodes, 1)[0]
     attr = list(graph.nodes.data()[random_node].keys())[0]
     graph.nodes[random_node][attr] = 0
```